# Elastic Search: To get all the document id depending on _field in source and update the _field with new data

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I wanted to fetch all the document ids present in elastic search repo depending on a field data and update that field with new data.

Ex: 
"_index": "conn2",
"_type": "conn2",
"_id": "doc1537857086536",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"suitename": "TestSuite"

I want to replace suitename with "TestSuite2" where suitename="TestSuite" for all the document id which contains "suitename": "TestSuite"

- I tried using Update API where as it is required to mention document id.

Please help me if any existing API i can use or any approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Update by Query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html).

Your call would look something like this:

[EDIT]: Updated this call to use a script to update the suitename field.

```
POST conn2/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.suitename = 'TestSuite2'",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "suitename": "TestSuite"
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could also use [_reindex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html).

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "conn2"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_index"
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "if (ctx._source.suitename == 'TestSuite') {ctx._source.suitename = 'TestSuite2'}",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Tim, I tried update_by_query?suitename=TestSuite2 where as it is throwing "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason": "request [/conn2/conn2/_update_by_query] contains unrecognized parameter: [suitename]"

Comment: What version of Elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: @ankitashukla - I updated the query. Should work for you now. It should all be in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) as well.

Comment: Thanks Tim- I am using Elastic Search-6.2.4. I have also used same update_by_query, but no data was getting updated. I read in one post re enabling dynamic scripting if I have to use mentioned update_by_query

Comment: You may need to enable dynamic scripting.